# Gnome Extension Testing

Tags: gnome, extension, testing

So I want to write a gnome extension.  The documentation https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/EcoDoc/FirstExtension is out of date and suggests using alt+f2 then entering r to restart gnome.  Problem is that current versions of ubuntu use use wayland and give 'restart is not available on wayland'.

How can I go about testing the extension without having to log out and log back in each time?  Is there a way I can spawn another session in the cli and use that to debug?

Comment: https://gjs.guide/extensions/development/debugging.html#reloading-extensions this link is the updated one.

Comment: awesome, thank you @PRATAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gjs.guide/extensions/development/debugging.html#reloading-extensions

Thanks @PRATAP for pointing out the new documentation which suggests the following to start a nested session

```
dbus-run-session -- gnome-shell --nested --wayland
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).